# Solving a wordsearch puzzle in matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

Posting the entirety of my code in the hope somebody can help me debug this crap. Really hoping to reach a conclusion soon because I've been toying with this for way too long.

I have here a function extract which is passed a grid of integers which represent letters (i.e A=1,Z=26) from my wordsearch function. Given a direction and a target word which is represented by a row vector of ints, it should iterate through the grid to find where the first letter exists and move in all directions from here for length of the word and extract the word e.g. if we are looking for [14, 5, 9, 2] and 14 is first positioned at (4,4) we should end up at (4,8).

The word is then compared in the search function and if it matches the target word, a line is drawn from first letter to the last on an image of the actual wordsearch.

I know my if and for loops are off in some places but I'm finding it difficult to correct my code so that it works. Help! One thing in particular I'm having difficulty with is controlling flow so that if after checking all directions from a square containing the first letter, the next instance of that letter is evaluated. Where would it be best to do this?

Code has lots of errors as it is and could do with a couple of pointers telling me where it needs altering or cleaning up.

```
%//A function to find a word in a grid.
function test = extract(grid, direction, target) 

%//switch through different cases that allow us to move to any adjacent cell to the current    
switch upper(direction)
    case 1 
        rowdir = -1; 
        coldir = 0; 
    case 2 
        rowdir = -1; 
        coldir = 1; 
    case 3 
        rowdir = 0; 
        coldir = 1; 
    case 4 
        rowdir = 1; 
        coldir = 1; 
    case 5 
        rowdir = 1; 
        coldir = 0; 
    case 6 
        rowdir = 1; 
        coldir = -1; 
    case 7 
        rowdir = 0; 
        coldir = -1; 
    case 8 
        rowdir = -1; 
        coldir = -1;  
end

[i, j] = size(grid); 
len = length(target); 
[row,column] = find(target(1)==grid); %//find the letter of the word we are looking for in grid
%//row and column of last letter having moved in a particular direction
rowN = row + (len-1) * rowdir; 
colN = column + (len-1) * coldir; 

%//trying to say here to only move in a particular direction if we don't go out of bounds. 
%//not sure I've succeeded
if (rowN > 1) | (rowN < i) | (colN > 1) | (colN < j) 
     testword = []; %empty array created
    for index = 1:len 
        index_1 = index-1;
        %//on loop get the letter in adjacent cell for direction we have moved
        word = grid(row + (index_1 * rowdir), column + (index_1 * coldir)); 
        testword{index} = word; %//letters are appended to create word for which we compare.
        %//get co-ords of start letter. change to pixel  co-ordinates so we can evaluate on image
        wordstart = [(row*30)-15, (column*30)-15 ]; 
        wordend = [((row + (len-1 * rowdir))*30)-15, ((column + (len-1 * coldir))*30)-15];
    end 
else
    word = '';
end 

  x1 = wordstart(1);
  x2 = wordend(1);
  y1 = wordstart(2);
  y2 = wordend(2);

  test = [ word , [x1,x2] , [y1,y2]]; %//only way I could think of to get all of these as outputs

end
```

---

```
%//test is the image we want to evaluate on
%//words is the list of words

function trial1 = wordsearch(test, words)

imagesc(test);
colormap(gray);
hold on;

grid = %//grid is a 15x15 matrix

[row, column] = size(grid); 

for iword = 1 : length(words) 
    target = char(words(iword)) - 'a' + 1;
    for i = 1:row 
        for j = 1:column 
            for direction_num = 1:8 %//for each direction
                direction = directions(direction_num, :);
                testword = extract(grid,direction,target); 
                if testword(1)==target %//if word we have extracted equals the target word

%//draw_line function takes x co-ordinates and y co-ordinates and plots line.
                    draw_line(testword(2),testword(3),testword(4),testword(5)); 
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

hold off;
end
```

---

@Dan

My extract function now looks like:

```
[i, j] = size(grid);
len = length(target); 
[row,column] = find(target(1)==grid);
for ii = 1:length(row)
    start_row = row(ii);
    start_column = column(ii); 
    rowN = start_row + len-1 * rowdir; 
    colN = start_column + len-1 * coldir; 
    if (rowN > 1) || (rowN < i) || (colN > 1) || (colN < j) 
        testword = [];
        for index = 1:len
        index_1 = index-1;
        word = grid(start_row + (index_1 * rowdir), start_column + (index_1 * coldir));
        testword{index} = word;
        wordstart = [(start_row*30)-15, (start_column*30)-15 ];
        wordend = [((start_row + (len-1 * rowdir))*30)-15, ((start_column + (len-1 * coldir))*30)-15];
        end 
    else

    end
end
```

What would I put as an else statement to check the word if previous in that particular direction takes you out of bounds?

Comment: There are many ways to get all the outputs, e.g. make a struct (`test.word = word; test.x = [x1,x2]...`) or else use multiple outputs: `function [word , X , Y]= extract(grid, direction, target)` and then at the end of your function have `X = [x1,x2]`

Answer (score 1):

```
for iword = 1 : length(words) 
    target = char(words(iword)) - 'a' + 1;
    for i = 1:row 
        for j = 1:column 
            for direction_num = 1:8 %//for each direction
```

For every word, you are looping through every element in the grid (i.e. the `i` and `j` loops) but you don't actually ever use these `i` or `j` values. So those two loops do nothing! This is because you seems to do all of that inside your `extract` function. So drop those two loops, they are wasting an inordinate amount of time.

Inside your `extract` function, you have a line `[row,column] = find...`. This will find **ALL** the possible starting points. So you actually need to loop through either of those somewhere. So instead of your `if (rowN > 1) | (rowN < i) | (colN > 1) | (colN < j)` I would suggest something more like:

```
for ii = 1:length(row)
    start_row = row(ii);
    start_column = column(ii); 
    %// And now re-use your code, but swap out all your row for start_row and your column for start_column
    .
    .
    .
end
```

That is the loop that will go through each of the possible starting letters.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I've now implemented those changes but I'm receiving out-of-bounds errors now for some reason when I'm convinced the code should be working. I don't think it's trying the new direction each time like it should be.

The first word in the list is 'Barry' and I have it returning the co-ordinates of everywhere B is in the grid just to check but I'm then getting this: 

Attempted to access grid(0,4); index must be a positive integer or logical.

Error in extract (line 42)
        word = grid(start_row + (index_1 * rowdir), start_column + (index_1
        * coldir));

Comment: @user3058703 but ya, that's because if there is a `B` near an edge, you're still comparing it to words that go past the edge. My suggestion is to pad your grid with a non letter character, like `'*'` for example around all edges by the number of characters of your longest word

Comment: Well the if statement inside the for loop of the extract function prevents you searching in a given direction if moving in that direction will take you out of bounds so all I need to do really is say in the else statement something like try next direction but not sure how that is possible.

Comment: @user3058703 There is no `if` statement inside the `for` loop of the `extract` function. But if you leave the `if (rowN > 1) | (rowN < i) | (colN > 1) | (colN < j) ` line in (but now change the `|`s to `||`s since you're dealing with scalars) then it checks the bounds for you and moves on for you...?

Comment: So what I'm expecting to happen is for example is if first B is found at column 2 and row 5 and the word is 'Barry' it should not move North or North East as length of word * column direction in these directions is less than 1 so instead, the next direction should be tried. If no success, then the next and so on until all have been tried, in which case try the next occurence of that letter.

Comment: @user3058703 just make certain that you calculate `rowN` etc **inside** your new for loop

Comment: @user3058703 That's clearly not how your code works. You check every starting letter for one direction before moving on to the next direction. All of that is already taken care of in your code... I think you should take a step back and have a critical read of the flow of your code to gain a better understanding of what is happening.

Comment: I've put an if statement in the for loop since making the changes you suggested as it seemed right to surely?

Comment: oh right of course, yeah. I've been chopping and changing parts of the code for ages now so confused myself as to how it worked.